# Erro ao tentar adicionar uma imagem como background de um button

Tags: android, button, background

Há alguns dias atrás, o Android Studio indicou que tinha atualizações que estavam disponíveis...

Eu já havia terminado um aplicativo há algum tempo e ele estava pronto para ser publicado e talz, só faltava a licença da Google Play que eu precisava comprar.

Comprei a licença e voltei ao Android Studio para implementar anúncios (adMob) e gerar a key.

Fui inventar de implementar a atualização do build gradle (era "opcional") no app e imediatamente o mesmo parou de funcionar...

Então eu estava refazendo-o até que precisei adicionar backgrounds aos buttons do aplicativo, assim como fiz no outro e por algum motivo o app não inicia e nenhum erro é acusado além desse:

```html
07-01 23:40:09.925 6690-6690/genesysgeneration.ruleoftree E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: genesysgeneration.ruleoftree, PID: 6690
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(146963896bytes) bitmap.
                                                                                at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
                                                                                at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:528)
                                                                                at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:17428)
                                                                                at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:17364)
                                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17176)
                                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
                                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17188)
                                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
                                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
                                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
                                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
                                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
                                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                                at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17188)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:753)
                                                                                at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
                                                                                at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
                                                                                at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
                                                                                at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2800)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2608)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2215)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sem a implementação dos backgrounds o mesmo funciona, é adicionar qualquer imagem e ele não funciona mais.

**Parte do código da activity**:

```js
package genesysgeneration.ruleoftree;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity01 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText et01, et02, et03;
    private TextView tv01/*, tvTest*/;
    private double l01, l02, l03, equalizer, lxx;
    private ImageView btnChange01, btnCompras, btnMoeda, btnInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main01);

        tv01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv01);
        tv01.setText(String.valueOf(0));

        l01=0;
        l02=0;
        l03=0;
        lxx=0;

        et01=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et01);
        et02=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et02);
        et03=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et03);

        addValuesDouble();

        btnChange01=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnChange01);
        Picasso.with().load(R.drawable.setas_03).into(btnChange01);
        btnChange01.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnCompras=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnCompras);
        btnCompras.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnMoeda=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnMoeda);
        btnMoeda.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnInfo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);
        btnInfo.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você parece estar carregando uma imagem muito grande no botão (pela mensagem do erro). Por que não troca o botão por uma imageView e usa o Picasso para carregar a imagem na mesma? Ele faz toda a decodificação da imagem para carregá-lá na tela.

Instala no Gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

E usa no código:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.image).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo de fazer isso com um button? Se for preciso coloco o código da activity no post.

Comment: Não precisa de botão. Usa uma imageView mesmo e seta um ClickListener na mesma para fazer o que o botão faria.

Comment: O que eu coloco nesse 'context'?

Comment: `Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.setas_03).into(btnChange01);` ficou dessa forma, porém o app para.

Comment: Imagino que o Picasso não funcione para botões. Como disse, você pode usar em ImageViews e fazer elas funcionarem como botões. Além disso, você pode usar o Picasso com outras ImageViews que carregam imagens. Por exemplo, a imagem de fundo. Não seria ela a imagem grande demais?

Comment: Eu troquei os buttons por imageViews e adicionei o ClickListener, única coisa que dá erro é o espaço onde preciso inserir o `context`.

Comment: Usa Picasso.with(this).

Comment: `Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.setas_03).into(btnChange01);` dá erro. Alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Qual erro que dá? Esse btnChange01 é um imageView?

Comment: Sim é. Erro => `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: genesysgeneration.ruleoftree, PID: 4321
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(146963896bytes) bitmap.`

Comment: Mas esse erro não parece estar relacionado com o Picasso. Checou qual a linha apontada pelo erro?

Comment: Olha, acabei de descobrir o erro. A imagem era muito grande e o AndroidStudio não estava conseguindo redimensioná-la na execução do app. Usei o modo comum de tratar o imageView, mas pretendo testar o Picasso posteriormente.

Comment: Mas o Picasso faz justamente o tratamento dessas imagens grandes e carrega no ImageView. Por isso sugeri usar ele para todas as imagens do seu app.